# How to put multiple markup inside asp listitems

Tags: asp.net

The HTML given to me has a series of checkboxes which I am trying to convert to a Checkboxlist.

The HTML is something like:

[] Label   Value

[] Label   Value

```
<div>
  <input>
  <label>
</div>
<div>
  <p id='row1' runat='server'>25</p>
</div>
```

Whenever I add this snippet between each `<asp:ListItem>` tags it gives two errors:

1."div can not be nested within element listitem"

2."Text property of asp:ListItem does not allow child objects"

I have also tried putting the snippet between asp:CheckBoxList and asp:ListItem but the first error still appears

I guess I understand the problem but I'm not sure of the solution. I need to be able to change "value" from the server to ensure validity else I would have used JQuery long ago.

Edit: I put markups inside like this:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:ListItem  value="item1">
<div>
  <input></input>
  <label></label>
</div>
<div>
  <p id='row1' runat='server'>25</p>
</div></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem  Value="item2">
<div>
  <input></input>
  <label></label>
</div>
<div>
  <p id='row2' runat='server'>25</p>
</div></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem  Value="item3">
<div>
  <input></input>
  <label></label>
</div>
<div>
  <p id='row3' runat='server'>25</p>
</div></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on code side how you are doing it

Comment: @Learning Added it.

Comment: `<asp:CheckBoxList />` is not a templatable control, you'll need to generate the HTML manually.